# IUPAC nomenclature of coordination complexes

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature, coordination-compounds, reference-request

Where can I get the latest rules on IUPAC nomenclature of coordination complexes?
I have J D Lee book which is also assumed to  have outdated rules.

Comment: You can refer Solomon and fryhle textbooks if you want

Answer (score 6):

I think IUPAC's Red Book in the [5th edition](http://old.iupac.org/publications/books/rbook/Red_Book_2005.pdf) by 2005, is the most recent reference of this topic, IR-9 (pages 142 onward) about coordination compounds.  Corrections of errors in the print are published [here](http://www.chem.qmul.ac.uk/iupac/bibliog/RBcorrect.html).

Answer (score 6):

In addition the correct reference to the current version of [*Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations 2005 (Red Book)*](http://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/databases/Red_Book_2005.pdf) given in [the answer by Buttonwood](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/59172/7951), you can find a short summary in the IUPAC Technical Report [Brief guide to the nomenclature of inorganic chemistry. *Pure Appl. Chem.* **2015,** *87*(9–10), 1039–1049](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/pac-2014-0718) as well as in the corresponding four-sided lift-out document, which is available as [supplementary material](http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/pac.2015.87.issue-9-10/pac-2014-0718/suppl/pac-2014-0718_Suppl.pdf).